# How can i get folder id of folders inside another folders in onedrive?

Tags: c#, onedrive

```
StringBuilder requestUri = new StringBuilder();
requestUri.AppendFormat(
    "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?access_token={0}",
    propriedades["access_token"]);

WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
string json = myWebClient.DownloadString(requestUri.ToString());
cloud = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Cloud>(json);
```

in this Json appears only informations of folders in root, like name, id..

How can i get folder id of folders inside another folders in onedrive? Using JSON i just can see folders id of folders in root, i cannot see folders id of folders inside another folders. For example, i have a folder id in root with name "Library" and inside this folder i have two folders with names "Book1" and "Book2", how can i get the folders id of these folders?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the direct question that you have, you will need to traverse the folders on your own.  The API calls only retrieve for the current level of folder structure.  They don't work like a Windows File system does

Additionally I agree with Fals that it might be easier to use APIs that make it nicer for you.
NOTE: Use the folder endpoint if looking at folders for ease of use.

[Here is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826531.aspx) the documentation as well.

Comment: In subsequent calls you will pass the folderid rather than the word files in the endpoint

Comment: Something like string.format("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/{0}?access_token={1}", "YourAccessToken", folder.FolderId) where folder is an object returned from the first call

Answer (score 0):

You should use the OneDrive C# API or  OneDrive JavaScript API, given that you need the JSON. The API is avaible at:

**[Working with Microsoft OneDrive folders and files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826531.aspx)**

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question.  The question is "How can I enumerate all folders."